# StopTheHostException while creating migration

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, exception, migration

I encountered a strange problem, and although I found mentions of it on the internet, none of them were helpful. 
This happens while the migration is being created. Just before this problem appeared, I added MediatR.DependencyInjection and AutoMapper.DependencyInjection, but I think this is not a problem. 
Maybe you have encountered a similar situation and you have a solution for it.

Below you can see the exception:

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostFactoryResolver+HostingListener+StopTheHostException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostFactoryResolver+HostingListener+StopTheHostException' was thrown.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostFactoryResolver.HostingListener.OnNext(KeyValuePair`2 value)
   at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticListener.Write(String name, Object value)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplicationBuilder.Build()
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in D:\repos\wisse\src\wisse.API\Program.cs:line 32
Done. To undo this action, use 'ef migrations remove'
```

Exception tells that problem occurs in 32 line in Program.cs. 
Here is Program.cs:

```
using System.Timers;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Events;
using wisse.Application;
using wisse.Domain;
using wisse.Infrastructure;

var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(config)
    .CreateLogger();

Log.Information("Application Starting...");

try
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    builder.Host.UseSerilog();

    // Add services to the container.
    builder.Services
        .AddDomain()
        .AddApplication()
        .AddInfrastructure(builder.Configuration);

    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

    var app = builder.Build();  // this is line 32

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseInfrastructure();
    app.Run();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
    throw;
}
```

For your information, all database configurations and DbContext are coming from `.AddInfrastructure(builder.Configuration)` and `app.UseInfrastructure();`

I have read a lot about this exception, but nothing seems to work for me :/ 
Currently the project (.NET 6) has only two entities and tables/entities from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore`

If you need more code, let me know:)